# Removing inline function call results in unresolved external symbol error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, inline

I was attempting to prove that you need a definition for an `inline` function in all TU's that use it. However, the following code compiles well (MSVS 2010):

#### inc.h

```
inline void foo();
```

#### test.cpp

```
#include "inc.h"

void x();
int main()
{
    foo();  // <--- compilation fails if I remove this call
    x();
    return 0;
}

void foo()
{
}
```

#### test2.cpp

```
#include "inc.h"

void x()
{
    foo();
}
```

Note the function calls are there to prevent optimizations. This compiles, although `foo` is declared `inline` and only defined in `test.cpp` but is also used in `test2.cpp`.

If I comment out the call to `foo` in `main()`, I get the expected error.

> "void __cdecl foo(void)" (?foo@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "void
>   __cdecl x(void)" (?x@@YAXXZ)  fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Why does having the `foo` call there matter? The code shouldn't work in either case, right?

Adding `extern` to `foo`'s declaration in `inc.h` also makes it compile (regardless of the call to `foo` in `main`).

Comment: Maybe you think of the "inline" keyword in a wrong way. "inline" should tell the linker that if it finds definition of "foo()" in multiple TUs, it is OK and linking should not fail with multiple-definitions error. I don't think it tells the linker that the definition of "foo()" should be in every TU. My guess is the linker is free to use any definition of "foo()" it finds in any of the processed TUs. Your test.obj contains the definition of "foo()" when you call it and it is thus available to the linker when processing test2.obj. When you dont call it in main(), no definition of "foo()"  exist

Comment: @DaliborFrivaldsky I'm surprised it doesn't fail with "undefined symbol" rather than "multiple defined symbol". **7.1.2/4** tells me this should happen - `An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly
the same definition in every case`

Comment: but "foo()" is not ODR-used in test2.cpp, as there is no definition of "foo()" provided when compiling test2.cpp. That would mean "foo()" does not have to be defined in test2.obj. Your quote from the standard doesn't say that the linker is thus forbidden from using any other definition of "foo()" found in other TUs

Comment: @DaliborFrivaldsky then why does it fail when removign the call to `foo`?

Comment: because it is not defined in any TU. Being an inline function, the compiler generates its definition only when it is used

Comment: @DaliborFrivaldsky also - "A non-overloaded function whose name appears
as a potentially-evaluated expression or a member of a set of candidate functions, if selected by overload
resolution when referred to from a potentially-evaluated expression, is odr-used, unless it is a pure virtual
function and its name is not explicitly qualified."

Comment: @HansPassant I agree. What I'm asking is - even though this compiles, is it legal?

Comment: The compiler is not obligated to *actually* inline the function.  It won't when it considers it too expensive to do so.  And will generate code that's an exact match for your top snippet.  The linker can't tell the difference, inline-ness is not encoded in the mangled symbol name for the function.  It could technically inject the definition with the *static* attribute and generate a link error that way but that's very inefficient, you still want a single definition of the non-inlined function in the final executable.

Comment: @HansPassant I agree. But that's beside what I'm asking. :) Is it legal?

Comment: Just look up 3.2/3: "no diagnostic required".  You didn't get one, that's legal.

Answer (score 2):

This is very clear in 3.2/3:

`...An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is used.`

If you don't define it in every such TU then all bets are off and *anything* the compiler does is fine, including appearing to work in some cases and failing to work in others.